# How would an operator $A$ in the Schrodinger and interaction picture be related if the commutation relation $[A_s,H_0] = 0$ holds?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, commutator, interactions

How would an operator A in the Schrodinger $A_s$ and interaction $A_I$ picture be related if the commutation relation

$$[A_s,H_0] = 0$$ holds where $H_0$ is a solved hamiltoniain.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple to see that they would be same. $$\begin{aligned}
        A_{s}(t) & = \text{exp}\left(-\imath H_{0} t\right)A_{s}\text{exp}\left(\imath H_{0} t\right) \\
                & = \sum_{n,m}\left(-\imath\right)^{n}\left(\imath\right)^{m}\frac{1}{n!m!}H_{0}^{n}A_{s}H_{0}^{m} \\
                & = \sum_{n,m}\left(-\imath\right)^{n}\imath^{m}\frac{1}{n!m!}A_{s}H_{0}^{n+m} \\
                & \left(\text{Since, } \left[A_{s},H_{0}\right]=0\right)\\
                & = A_{s} 
    \end{aligned}$$

Comment: im not sure though how that show the interaction and schrodinger picture are the same though